# MST, Cut in Graph, Some Claims?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, trees, algebraic-graph-theory

I ready for taking a P.hD Entrance Exam. one of old-solution problem of Data Structure is as follows:

Which of the following Claims is True about `MST` of Simple, Undirected, Weighted and Connected Graph `G`? (edge weights is not necessarily different.)

1) if lightest edge between any cut in G, be unique, then `MST` is unique.

2)If all edges weights be different, `MST` is unique.

3) if the weights of `e=(u, v)` be equal to maximum lightest edge in all paths between u and `v` then `e` be in the `MST`.

Answer: one of them is Correct.

Who can explain more, which is true? why? there is any proof or we must take an example or provide counterexample?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35409184/781723

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that 2 is true, consider two different MSTs $T_1$ and $T_2$; we will show that either $T_1=T_2$ (i.e. they are not different) or one of them is not actually minimal.  Since they are both minimum, the sum of each's edge weight is the same.  Say the edges of $T_1$ are $e_1 < e_2 < ... < e_n$ and the edges of $T_2$ are $f_1 < f_2 < ... < f_n$.
Since the trees are different (by hypothesis) there is (at least) one edge that is different: say $e_i\in T_1$ and $e_i\notin T_2$... choose $e_i$ as the smallest edge with this property i.e. $e_1=f_1, e_2=f_2, ..., e_{i-1}=f_{i-1}$ and $e_{i} < f_{i}$.

Then, add $e_{i}$ to $T_{2}$. You created a cycle, so now we delete an edge to make it a tree.  Delete the edge of maximum weight on the cycle, $f_{j}$.  Provided that the edge we deleted ($f_j$) isn't $e_{i}$ then the new Tree $T_{2}+e_{i}-f_{j}$ has lower weight than $T_{2}$ and hence $T_{2}$ wasn't a MST (contradiction).  Now, we just have to show that $e_{i}$ is not $f_{j}$.

If $e_{i}$ is $f_{j}$ that means that the edge we added was the heaviest edge on the cycle (had largest weight).  If this is the case, then every edge on the cycle is lighter and therefore comes earlier in the ordering (i.e. all the edges on the cycle have subscripts smaller than $i$).  But, then all these edges are also in $T_1$ and $e_i$ is in $T_1$, but $T_1$ is a tree and contains no cycle.  Therefore, there is an edge on the cycle that is not in $T_{1}$ and hence has more weight than $e_{i}$.  Thus, $e_{i}$ is not $f_{j}$.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph, It may be that 1 is also true... but I did not immediately see a proof.

Comment: Please complete it to approve

Comment: @user4249446, I would write more except I feel that the person asking the question ought to provide more effort than the respondent (me).  If he/she explains what he/she has done in greater detail, then I am happy to provide more information.

Comment: @DaviedZuhraph, explain what you've done and where you're stuck, then I'll help.  You also need to clarify your question.  I assume for 1 you mean "every cut C contains a unique lightest edge" and I assume you mean that a cut is a set of edges that, if removed, result in a disconnected graph.